# OK button in a dialog popup not working in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, dialog, popup

I am new to learning flex and I have this application which opens up a popup displays some checkbox values and the once the user clicks the OK button populates an array and then closes. But in my code, when I click the OK button nothing happens.

```
 private function closeDialog(event : CloseEvent) : void {
        PopUpManager.removePopUp(this); // close this dialog
    }

    private function onClickOK (event : CloseEvent) : void {
           var values:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        for (i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            var row:Array = table.getItemAt(i);
            if (row["selected"]) {
                var valueRow:Array = new Array();
                arrayRow["colA"] = row["colA"];
                values.addItem(valueRow);
            }
        }

        page.model["choosenvalues"] = values;

        closeDialog(event);
    }
```

And here is the flex code

```
   <mx:VBox paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10">
    <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Spacer width="2%" />
        <mp:Table id="selectTable" dataProvider="{table}" title="" height="350">
            <mp:columns>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="selected" headerText="  "  editable="true" textAlign="center" minWidth="36" width="36" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0">
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                            <mx:CheckBox width="18" click="{data.selected = !data.selected}" label="" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0"/>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Column A" minWidth="240" dataField="colA"/>

            </mp:columns>
        </mp:Table>
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:HBox width="100%">
        <mx:Spacer width="85%" />
        <mx:Button label="OK" click="onClickOK(null)" enabled="true"/>
        <mx:Button label="Cancel" click="closeDialog(null)"/>
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:VBox>
```

Comment: Looks good. Show the full code please. Are you sure that 'table' dataProvider is not null??

Comment: Yes, I am very sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the event parameters from methods, since you don't use them. Anyway, the *onclick* handler should accept *MouseEvent* or just *Event*, not *CloseEvent*.

```
private function closeDialog() : void {
    PopUpManager.removePopUp(this); // close this dialog
}

private function onClickOK () : void {
       ...

    closeDialog();
}
```

MXML:

```
<mx:Button label="OK" click="onClickOK()" enabled="true"/>
<mx:Button label="Cancel" click="closeDialog()"/>
```

Note: parameterless event handlers are possible with MXML, since if you try it with AS, you'll get warnings.

Comment: I tried removing the event parameters, but still didn't work. However, I replaced the call to closeDialog() with PopUpManager.removePopUp(this); and it works fine.